# type casting shared memory pointer to integer pointer

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, shared-memory

```
int main()
{
    key_t key = ftok("yu", 65);
    int shmid = shmget(key, 100 * sizeof(int), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    int** Matr = (int**)shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<3; j++)
        {
            Matr[i][j] = i + j; // writing to shared memory
        }
    }

    shmdt(Matr);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to type cast the shared memory pointer to integer double pointer however every time I compile the code, it says that segmentation fault(core dumped). Can someone tell me how to do this? Thanks in advance.

P.S : I am doing this on C++.

Comment: Every process has its own address space, if you are really sharing a pointer between them, don't. Otherwise please show a [mcve].

Comment: If you get any compilation error/warning - please share them. "every time I compile the code, it says that segmentation fault" - _segmentation fault_ is a run time issue (not a compilation problem), unless you mean the compiler itself crashed.

Comment: @Quimby so what do you suggest? it is my assignment in which I am required to add two matrixes column by column using shared memory by creating processes equal to number of columns.

Comment: @Quimby I think the usage of shared memory is, in principle, valid. Each process will have it's own pointer(s), but the underlying data will be shared between processes.

Comment: A side note: in "real life" I would use threads (within one process) rather than processes to perform such a task. Threads are more lightweight, and share memory address space.

Comment: @SohaibsAmir I am not suggesting anything so far because I do not know what exactly are you doing([mcve]). Shared memory is fine, sharing pointers to memory is wrong because the shared memory will likely be mapped at different addresses for each process. If you need to communicate to some process which column from the shared memory it shoud use, just use integer as offset.

Comment: @wohlstad Yes, it is fine, but you cannot share that pointer into this memory.

Comment: @wohlstad I even tried int* arr = (int*)shmat(shmid,(void*)0,0) and then assigned the address of arr to int** mat but it still didn't work. Does this imply that the double pointers are mapped in a different way in the memory?

Comment: @SohaibsAmir As has already been stated twice you need to provide a [mcve].  The problem almost certainly lies with how you use `mat` after the assignment.

Comment: @SohaibsAmir shared memory is basically a block of bytes. It is up to you to interpret them as containing `int`s, `double`s etc. (similar to the way you use `malloc`). If you'll post a [mre] maybe we'll have more insights into your problem.

Comment: @wohlstad I have posted the full code in which I am basically writing a matrix into the shared memory but the problem is same I shared above. The question is why it is not writing the data into shared memory and how do I resolve it?

Comment: You have to check the return values from `ftok`, `shmget`, `shmat`. Each of them can fail (e.g. `flok` returns -1 upon failure, check the documentation for the other 2). This will bring you closer to making it work.

Comment: Also since `Matr` is a `int**` (not int[][]) I don't think it's valid to access it with [][] (because the compiler cannot know the matrix stride). it could be that `Matr` is an array of row pointers, but I don't see where you initialize them.

Comment: You're essentially treating the shared memory block as an array of `int *` elements: what do you expect those pointers to point to?  You should first get your code working without the added complication of shared memory or multiple processes.

Comment: Consider to make make `Matr` an `int*` (i.e. a 1D continous block of memory). Then you can access the (i,j) element by using `Matr[j * width + i]`.

Comment: I think you are supposed to make your `Matr` an `int [rows][cols]` (a single block of memory) or model it as `int *` (again pointing to a single block of memory with you doing the row/col calculation manually), not as pointers to pointers to int. If you remove that indirection the problem of different address spaces goes away.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code.

The main difference is that the matrix is implemented with a **1D** continous block of memory (an array), and therefore `Matr` is of type `int*`.

The management of the 2D indices of the matrix is done "manually" by calculating an index in the array (`idx`) from the 2 matrix indices (`i,j`).

**Note:** I advise you to add error handling for all the system calls.

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

int main()
{
    key_t key = ftok("yu", 65);
    // check if key is -1 and if so handle the error ...
    int shmid = shmget(key, 100 * sizeof(int), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    // check if shmid is -1 and if so handle the error ...
    int* Matr = (int*)shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);
    // check if Matr is (void*)-1 and if so handle the error ...

    int width = 3;
    int height = 3;
    // NOTE: width * height must be <= 100 (according to the declared size of the shared memory).

    for (int j = 0; j<height; ++j)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<width; ++i)
        {
            int idx = j * width + i;
            Matr[idx] = i + j; // writing to shared memory
        }
    }

    int st = shmdt(Matr);
    // check if st is -1 and if so handle the error ...
    return 0;
}
```